Optimal arbitrage amount between uniswap V2 and V3
since we can get the optimal arbitrage amount by price impact formula between 2 uniswap v2 markets, how could i approach to calculate the optimal amount between an uniswap v2 - with constant product curve and uniswap v3 (but one tick only which would then be a linear curve)?


how could i approach to calculate the optimal amount between an uniswap v2 - with constant product curve and uniswap v3

You check different market deptjs on Uniswap v3, as you would do on a centralised exchange order book.
Because this operation is more data intensive, I do not think you can do it without constantly tracking Uniswap v3 ticks/market depths offchain.
